# Changing parameters on iOS device orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a Tabbar project in which one one the tabs should be on landscape mode. I've seen than the Tabbar controller only allows it only if all its views allow it. Son now I'm somehow forced to adapt  all the views for both portrait and landscape mode, which I've never did before.

Am I right assuming that all should be done under:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation...
```

so what happens with subview which are lazyly initialized? such as a footerView on a tableView?

Another thing is, I have a method to scroll the tableView so nothing is kept under the keyboard when it's called. The method uses a constant float + a variable. In landscape mode, the constant should be another.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on autoresizingmask - setting this attribute on your views will automate a lot of the orientation resizing.
And yes, you'll need a landscape and a portrait value for your constant.

Comment: Oh boy! Thanks. How do I detect whether is it in landscape or portrait orientation? So far I'm reading self.view.frame.size.width and go from there, but I don't know if it is a good practice.

Comment: You can check [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation - search Stack Overflow for UIDeviceOrientation, there are many great posts on how to do that.